# How to determine programmatically the current active profile using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way programmatically to get the current active profile within my bean?

Answer (score 339, accepted):

It doesn't matter is your app Boot or just raw Spring. There is just enough to inject `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` to your bean.

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
....

this.environment.getActiveProfiles();
```

Comment: Thanks. how would you create different property files for different profiles?

Comment: It's definitely the separate SO question. However you can take a look to Boot docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: Getting environment as null

Comment: same - getting env as null

Comment: Perhaps the place you’d like to autowire is not a spring bean. Better to ask a new SO question with more info.