# How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I want to access values provided in `application.properties`, e.g.:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
logging.file=${HOME}/application.log

userBucket.path=${HOME}/bucket
```

I want to access `userBucket.path` in my main program in a Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 810, accepted):

You can use the `@Value` annotation and access the property in whichever Spring bean you're using

```
@Value("${userBucket.path}")
private String userBucketPath;
```

The [Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) section of the Spring Boot docs, explains all the details that you might need.

Comment: as en alternative one can get those also from spring `Environment` or via `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: To add on top of @sodik's answer, this is an example  that shows how to get the [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392231/how-to-determine-programmatically-the-current-active-profile-using-spring-boot

Comment: What if you need to access over 10 values, Would you have to keep repeating your example 10times?

Comment: one approach would be to do so, but its cumbersome. There are alternative approaches based on `@Configuration` classes,  problem is well analyzed in the following [blog post](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-injecting-property-values-into-configuration-beans/)

Comment: Adding this answer you can add some value if the property configuration is not found by default some value adding: @Value("${userBucket.path:~/bucket}") or empty @Value("${userBucket.path:}")

Comment: Note, this only works on a `@Component` (or any of its derivatives, i.e. `@Repository`, etc.)

Comment: I use this on Controller and it's work

Comment: I used it on a `@Component` and it didn't work. All the variables just end up being `null`. Is it somewhat different if I use an `application.yml`?

Comment: This works great. Also make sure you don't declare the variable as static. This will cause the binding to silently fail.

Answer (score 360):

Another way is injecting `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` to your bean.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
....

public void method() {
    .....  
    String path = env.getProperty("userBucket.path");
    .....
}
```

Comment: that's really useful when you have to access multiple vars. Good advice

Comment: also useful when the name of the property you need to access changes dynamically

Comment: What if you want to search the properties?  And may I suggest including the import statement so all can see the Environment package name, probably org.springframework.core.env.Environment

Comment: Also very useful when you want to enforce the existence of a property via getRequiredProperty:  env.getRequiredProperty("userBucket.path");

Comment: Be careful not to import the wrong Environment. I intellij auto-imported the CORBA Environment.

Comment: Why is my env null?

Comment: @JanacMeena had the same problem of the IntelliJ auto-importing CORBA's class instead of `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`

Comment: This one works for me, unlike the `@Value`-solution which did not

Answer (score 76):

`@ConfigurationProperties` can be used to map values from `.properties`( `.yml` also supported) to a POJO.

Consider the following Example file.

**.properties**

```
cust.data.employee.name=Sachin
cust.data.employee.dept=Cricket
```

**Employee.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cust.data.employee")
@Configuration("employeeProperties")
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String dept;

    //Getters and Setters go here
}
```

Now the properties value can be accessed by autowiring `employeeProperties` as follows.

```
@Autowired
private Employee employeeProperties;

public void method() {

   String employeeName = employeeProperties.getName();
   String employeeDept = employeeProperties.getDept();

}
```

Comment: i used this way and got null return, i put my properties file in src/test/resources and properties java class (in which the properties value being saved) in src/main/package/properties. what i been missing? thanks

Comment: you have to save the files to `src/main/resources` if you are not testing your code from a Spring test.

Comment: Same as @AhmadLeoYudanto and there is nothing I can do that change that

Answer (score 42):

Currently, I know about the following three ways:

**1. The `@Value` annotation**

```
@Value("${<property.name>}")
private static final <datatype> PROPERTY_NAME;
```

- In my experience there are some situations when you are not
  able to get the value or it is set to `null`.
  For instance, when you try to set it in a `preConstruct()` method or an `init()` method. This happens because the value injection happens after the class is fully constructed. This is why it is better to use the third option.

**2. The `@PropertySource` annotation**

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

// 'env' is an Environment variable
env.getProperty(configKey);
```

- `PropertySouce` sets values from the property source file in an `Environment` variable (in your class) when the class is loaded.
  So you able to fetch easily afterword.
- Accessible through System Environment variable.

**3. The `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.**

- This is mostly used in Spring projects to load configuration properties.
- It initializes an entity based on property data.
- `@ConfigurationProperties` identifies the property file to load.
- `@Configuration` creates a bean based on configuration file variables.

  ```
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
    @Configuration("UserData")
    class user {
      // Property & their getter / setter
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserData userData;

    userData.getPropertyName();
  ```

Comment: What if the default location is overridden with `spring.config.location`?  Does #2 still work?

Comment: In such case, priority comes into the place. As per i know when you set spring.config.location using command line it have high priority so it override existing one.

Comment: Many thanks for this >> "In my experience there are some situations when you are not able to get the value or it is set to null. For instance, when you try to set it in a preConstruct() method or an init() method. This happens because the value injection happens after the class is fully constructed. This is why it is better to use the 3'rd option."<<

Answer (score 18):

You can do it this way as well....

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ConfigProperties {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getConfigValue(String configKey){
        return env.getProperty(configKey);
    }
}
```

Then wherever you want to read from application.properties, just pass the key to getConfigValue method.

```
@Autowired
ConfigProperties configProp;

// Read server.port from app.prop
String portNumber = configProp.getConfigValue("server.port");
```

Comment: What package is `Environment`?

Comment: Find it here: org.springframework.core.env.Environment

Comment: What if the default location is overridden with `spring.config.location`?

Comment: Why do you need `@PropertySource` when you inject Spring `Environment` which reads properties from `application.properties` file by default?

Answer (score 15):

Follow these steps.

1. Create your configuration class like below. You can see:

   ```
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

   @Configuration
   public class YourConfiguration {

       // Passing the key which you set in application.properties
       @Value("${userBucket.path}")
       private String userBucket;

       // Getting the value from that key which
       // you set in application.properties
       @Bean
       public String getUserBucketPath() {
           return userBucket;
       }
   }
   ```
2. When you have a configuration class then inject in the variable from a configuration where you need.

   ```
   @Component
   public class YourService {

       @Autowired
       private String getUserBucketPath;

       // Now you have a value in the getUserBucketPath
       // variable automatically.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `@Value` to load variables from the `application.properties` if you will use this value in one place, but if you need a more centralized way to load these variables `@ConfigurationProperties` is a better approach.

Additionally, you can load variables and cast them automatically if you need different data types to perform your validations and business logic.

```
application.properties
custom-app.enable-mocks = false

@Value("${custom-app.enable-mocks}")
private boolean enableMocks;
```

Comment: The casting is very nice.  What additional is necessary as I get "Annotations not allowed here" no matter where I put it.  I am missing something.  Do I need a some other per-configuration to use this annotation anywhere?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `@Value("${property-name}")` from the
application.properties if your class is annotated with
`@Configuration` or `@Component`.

There's one more way I tried out was making a Utility class to read properties in the following way -

```
 protected PropertiesUtility () throws IOException {
    properties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = 
   getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
    properties.load(inputStream);
}
```

You can make use of static method to get the value of the key passed as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped in case where i couldn't CDI :)

Answer (score 7):

To pick the values from property file, we can have a *Config* reader class, something like *ApplicationConfigReader.java*.
Then define all the variables against properties. Refer to the below example,

```
application.properties

myapp.nationality: INDIAN
myapp.gender: Male
```

Below is the corresponding reader class.

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
class AppConfigReader{
    private String nationality;
    private String gender

    // Getter and setter
}
```

Now we can auto-wire the reader class wherever we want to access property values.

E.g.,

```
@Service
class ServiceImpl{
    @Autowired
    private AppConfigReader appConfigReader;

    //...
    // Fetching values from the configuration reader
    String nationality = appConfigReader.getNationality() ;
    String gender = appConfigReader.getGender();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should inject `@Autowired private Environment env;` from `import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;`

And then use it this way:

`env.getProperty("yourPropertyNameInApplication.properties")`

Answer (score 6):

An application can read three types of values from the *application.properties* file.

### **application.properties**

```
my.name = kelly

my.dbConnection = {connection_srting:'http://localhost:...', username:'benz', password:'pwd'}
```

### Class file

```
@Value("${my.name}")
private String name;

@Value("#{${my.dbConnection}}")
private Map<String,String> dbValues;
```

If you don't have a property in *application.properties* then you can use the default value:

```
@Value("${your_name: default value}")
private String msg;
```

Comment: `connection_srting` can't be right.

Answer (score 6):

**@Value** Spring annotation is used for injecting values into fields in Spring-manged beans, and it can be applied to the field or constructor/method parameter level.

Examples

1. **String** value from the annotation to the field

```java
    @Value("string value identifire in property file")
    private String stringValue;
```

2. We can also use the @Value annotation to inject a **Map** property.

   First, we'll need to define the property in the `{key: ‘value' }` form in our properties file:

```java
   valuesMap={key1: '1', key2: '2', key3: '3'}
```

Not that the values in the Map must be in single quotes.

Now inject this value from the property file as a Map:

```java
   @Value("#{${valuesMap}}")
   private Map<String, Integer> valuesMap;
```

To get the value of a specific key

```java
   @Value("#{${valuesMap}.key1}")
   private Integer valuesMapKey1;
```

3. We can also use the @Value annotation to inject a **List** property.

```java
   @Value("#{'${listOfValues}'.split(',')}")
   private List<String> valuesList;
```

Comment: how about objects?

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 ways to read the `application.properties`:

1st way:

Using `@Value`, `EnvironmentInterface` and `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```
@Value("${userBucket.path}")
private String value;
```

2nd way:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment; // org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

String s = environment.getProperty("userBucket.path");
```

3rd way:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("userbucket")
public class Config {
   
    private String path;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Can be read with getters and setters..

Reference - [here](https://javainfinite.com/spring-boot/how-to-read-values-from-application-properties-in-springboot/)

Comment: It would be really helpful if you added the import statements for Value, Environment, ad ConfigurationProperties

Comment: Don't forget (1) the class should be annotated with something like `@Component`, and (2) you cannot make your member/variable static for `@Value` to work.

Answer (score 4):

1. Injecting a property with the @Value annotation is straightforward:

   ```
   @Value("${jdbc.url}")
   private String jdbcUrl;
   ```
2. We can obtain the value of a property using the *Environment* API

   ```
   @Autowired
   private Environment env;
   ...
   dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
   ```

Comment: Where is setUrl defined? How come I get a compiler error. Actually I'm more interested in setPassword if possible. Thanks.

Comment: For #1 above, don't forget (1) the class should be annotated with something like `@Component`, and (2) you cannot make your member/variable static for `@Value` to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `@Value` annotation for reading values from an application.properties/yml file.

```java
@Value("${application.name}")
private String applicationName;
```

Comment: form which library value you imported?

Comment: Don't forget (1) the class should be annotated with something like `@Component`, and (2) you cannot make your member/variable static for `@Value` to work.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to access the value from the *application.properties* file:

1. Using the @Value annotation

   ```
   @Value("${property-name}")
   private data_type var_name;
   ```
2. Using an instance of the *Environment* class

   ```
   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

   // Access this way in the method where it's required

   data_type var_name = environment.getProperty("property-name");
   ```

You can also inject an instance of the environment using constructor injection or creating a bean yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually three ways to read the *application.properties* file,

Using Environment,

```
@Autowired
Environment environment

environment.getProperty({propertyName})
```

Or we can use @Value,

```
@Value("${property}")
```

but the problem with @Value is it might throw an exception if the value is not in the properties file.

The suggested way is using @ConfigurationProperties

```
@ConfigurationProperties("userBucket")
public class test{
  private String path;
  //getters and setters
}
```

For a detailed example - [Reading application.properties](https://javainfinite.com/spring-boot/how-to-read-values-from-application-properties-in-springboot/).

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot allows us several methods to provide externalized configurations. You can try using file *application.yml* or YAML files instead of the property file and provide different property files setup according to different environments.

We can separate out the properties for each environment into separate YAML files under separate Spring profiles. Then during deployment you can use:

```
java -jar -Drun.profiles=SpringProfileName
```

to specify which Spring profile to use. Note that the YAML files should be named like

```
application-{environmentName}.yml
```

for them to be automatically taken up by Spring Boot.

Reference: *[2. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)*

To read from the *application.yml* or property file:

The **easiest way** to read a value from the property file or YAML is to use the Spring @value annotation. Spring automatically loads all values from the YAML file to the Spring environment, so we can directly use those values from the environment like:

```
@Component
public class MySampleBean {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String sampleName;

    // ...

}
```

Or another method that Spring provides to read strongly-typed [beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) is as follows:

```
YML

ymca:
    remote-address: 192.168.1.1
    security:
        username: admin
```

Corresponding [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) to read the YAML content:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("ymca")
public class YmcaProperties {
    private InetAddress remoteAddress;
    private final Security security = new Security();
    public boolean isEnabled() { ... }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) { ... }
    public InetAddress getRemoteAddress() { ... }
    public void setRemoteAddress(InetAddress remoteAddress) { ... }
    public Security getSecurity() { ... }
    public static class Security {
        private String username;
        private String password;
        public String getUsername() { ... }
        public void setUsername(String username) { ... }
        public String getPassword() { ... }
        public void setPassword(String password) { ... }
    }
}
```

The above method works well with YAML files.

Reference: *[2. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)*

Comment: Also note.. you cannot make your member/variable static for `@Value` to work.

Answer (score 2):

The best ways to get property values are using:

**1. Using Value annotation**

```
@Value("${property.key}")
private String propertyKeyVariable;
```

**2. Using the *Environment* bean**

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

public String getValue() {
    return env.getProperty("property.key");
}

public void display() {
    System.out.println("# Value : " + getValue);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget (1) the class should be annotated with something like `@Component`, and (2) you cannot make your member/variable static for `@Value` to work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways,

1. you can directly use `@Value` in your class

   ```java
   @Value("#{'${application yml field name}'}")
   public String ymlField;
   ```

*Or*

2. To make it clean you can clean `@Configuration` class where you can add all your `@value`

   ```java
   @Configuration
   public class AppConfig {

       @Value("#{'${application yml field name}'}")
       public String ymlField;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try class [PropertiesLoaderUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderUtils.html). This approach doesn’t use any annotation of Spring Boot. It is a traditional class way.

Example:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/application.properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
String url_server=props.getProperty("server_url");
```

Use the getProperty() method to pass the key and access the value in the properties file.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to find a key/value in the configuration.

```java
...
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
...
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment  myEnv;

...
  
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void doSomethingAfterStartup() 
    throws Exception {
        
        LOG.info("myEnv (userBucket.path): " + myEnv.getProperty("userBucket.path"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's how to programmatically get property values.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the application.properties file values by using:

```
@Value("${key_of_declared_value}")
```

Comment: Don't forget (1) the class should be annotated with something like `@Component`, and (2) you cannot make your member/variable static for `@Value` to work.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to use the `@Value` annotation. It will automatically assign a value to your object `private Environment en`.

This will reduce your code, and it will be easy to filter your files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @Value annotation and access the property in a Spring bean:

```
@Value("${userBucket.path}")
private String userBucketPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the above did directly work for me.
I did the following:

In addition to [Rodrigo Villalba Zayas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot/38314645#38314645), I added `implements InitializingBean` to the class and implemented the method

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    String path = env.getProperty("userBucket.path");
}
```

So that will look like

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
public class xyz implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    private String path;

    ....

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        path = env.getProperty("userBucket.path");
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. But there is a very simple solution. Just declare your variable in the constructor.

My example:

**application.propperties:**

```
#Session
session.timeout=15
```

**SessionServiceImpl class:**

```
private final int SESSION_TIMEOUT;
private final SessionRepository sessionRepository;

@Autowired
public SessionServiceImpl(@Value("${session.timeout}") int sessionTimeout,
                          SessionRepository sessionRepository) {
    this.SESSION_TIMEOUT = sessionTimeout;
    this.sessionRepository = sessionRepository;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ConfigurationProperties. It's simple and easy to access a value defined in *application.properties*:

```
# Datasource
app.datasource.first.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/ovtools?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
app.datasource.first.username=
app.datasource.first.password=
app.datasource.first.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
server.port=8686
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=mysql
```

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "tracenvDb")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource.first")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSourceanomalie() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "JdbcTemplateenv")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateanomalie(@Qualifier("tracenvDb") DataSource datasourcetracenv) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(datasourcetracenv);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**application.yml or application.properties**

```
config.value1: 10
config.value2: 20
config.str: This is a simle str
```

**MyConfig class**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public class MyConfig {
    int value1;
    int value2;
    String str;

    public int getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    // Add the rest of getters here...      
    // Values are already mapped in this class. You can access them via getters.
}
```

**Any class that wants to access config values**

```
@Import(MyConfig.class)
class MyClass {
    private MyConfig myConfig;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(MyConfig myConfig) {
        this.myConfig = myConfig;
        System.out.println( myConfig.getValue1() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the @Value annotation provided by Spring Boot. You need to define a variable at class level. For example:

@Value("${userBucket.path}")
private String userBucketPath

There is another way you can do this via the Environment Class. For example:

1. Autowire the environment variable to your class where you need to access this property:

@Autowired
private Environment environment

2. Use the environment variable to get the property value in the line you need it using:

environment.getProperty("userBucket.path");

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

To read `application.properties` or `application.yml` attributes follow the following steps:

1. Add your attributes in application.properties or application.yaml
2. Create config class and add your attributes

```
application.jwt.secretKey=value
application.jwt.tokenPrefix=value
application.jwt.tokenExpiresAfterDays=value ## 14
```

```yaml
application:
  jwt:
    secret-key: value
    token-prefix: value
    token-expires-after-days: value ## 14
```

```java
@Configuration("jwtProperties") // you can leave it empty
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.jwt") // prefix is required
public class JwtConfig {
    private String secretKey;
    private String tokenPrefix;
    private int tokenExpiresAfterDays;

    // getters and setters
}
```

NOTE: in `.yaml` file you have to use kabab-case

Now to use the config class just instantiate it, you can do this manualy or with dependency injection.

```java
public class Target {

  private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

  @Autowired
  public Target(JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
      this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
  }

  // jwtConfig.getSecretKey()

}
```