# Spring Boot Custom Properties - How to include externalize properties when class is not in the application context

Tags: spring-boot, properties, configuration

It is hard to understand but for my application a required format. I have some custom libraries which are included at runtime and so they are not in the spring application context. To get apis from spring boot application I catched required apis and overhand this to my external classes.

To show an example:

```
HashValueService hashValueService 
   = (HashValueService) appContext.getBean("hashValueServiceImpl");

ServiceList srvList = new ServiceList();
    srvList.setHashValueService(hashValueService);
```

In this way I'm able to get access to my database, which is in my application context.

I have a lot of properties distributed in the whole application. So I want to use the default application.properties to centralized often used properties in my application, like the keystore.

For that I edited application.properties with this line:

```
application.keystore=server.jks
```

But of course the usage of the Spring's @Value does show me a null for that attribute, because this class is not in my application context:

```
@Value("${application.keystore}")
private String keystore;
```

Do you have an idea to overhand this properties to this customer libraries? Maybe the creation of a new property file whould help? Thank u a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Majority of Spring magic is done by `BeanPostProcessor`s. Take a good look at them - [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html).

`@Value` wiring (and much more) is performed by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, you can use it for your purpose:

```
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor beanPostProcessor = 
          appContext.getBean(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class);
ServiceList srvList = new ServiceList();

beanPostProcessor.processInjection(srvList);
```

After that, your `ServiceList` should have `String keystore` field initialized.

Comment: This is it! Thanks for that! You made me happy!

Comment: What is with properties I want to use in the main-method? @Value returns me null and the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor can't be used at this place. I'm using SpringApplicationBuilder to create two apis for incomming requests.

Comment: @MissBonbon do you mean public static void main(String[]) method?

Comment: yes, this is what i mean. Found this question on stack: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot) - But this not work for me in the first try.

Comment: @MissBonbon `main` is a static method. Properties can be injected into spring components (beans) which are instances of classes (not static) - don't go that way :)

Comment: What should i rather do? Have u got a link to an good example?

Comment: @MissBonbon To be honest - I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, and comments are probably not the best place to talk since it's difficult to include code here. I recommend you creating a new question where you can explain the problem (and expectations) more deeply. Feel free to share a link to the question here.

Comment: Hopped you will have an idea. You are right! This need a deeper explanation. Thank for your time to answer.