# Spring Boot - set value from an external properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot

I have an external location set on my `application.properties` as below

```
spring.config.location=file:${catalina.home}/conf/app.properties
```

`app.properties` has a property as `timeOut=10000`. There are many other properties as well.

I need to set this property on my session something like this:

```
 session.setMaxInactiveInterval(timeOut_Property);
```

How can this be achieved?

Adding Controller:

```
@Controller
public class StartController  {

@Value("${spring.config.location.defaultTimeout}")
private int defaultTimeout;

@RequestMapping("login.do")
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, Model model) {     
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(defaultTimeout);     
    return null;        
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Comment: @Rjiuk That is probably when there is a single property defined.

Comment: Have you tried it ? I am pretty sure it works as well with one as with many properties files

Comment: It gives the below exception: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'timeOut' in value "${timeOut}" Have tried with ${spring.config.location}, ${spring.config.location.timeOut} as well

Comment: can you give your main app code? where you import your properties for spring-boot?

Comment: Looks like you haven't added your properties file which has timeOut value.

Comment: Import your custom property file in main class like
@PropertySource(name = "general-properties", value = { "classpath:path to your app.properties"})
public class MainApplication {
}

Comment: @Rjiuk Added controller code. The properties file is in place

Comment: @Rjiuk I was deploying using Spring Boot app and not tomcat - that's why it couldnt find tomcat directory. My bad! Plus the PropertySource as mentioned by Afridi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Main Application class should look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(name = "general-properties", value = { "classpath:path to your app.properties"})
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NayapayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And change your controller to:

```
@Controller
public class StartController  {

    @Value("${timeOut}")
    private int defaultTimeout;

    @RequestMapping("login.do")
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, Model model) {     
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(defaultTimeout);     
        return null;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the variable with this property in the class as:

```
@Value("${timeOut}")
private String timeOut;
```

Use this variable to set session inactive interval as:

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(timeOut);
```