# Spring Boot read value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, application.properties

In my application.properties I have defined port and server context.

```
server.port=8080
server.context-path=/SekcjaN
```

How to read value context to insert it into RequestMapping value in controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = server.context-path+"/auth")
public class AuthController extends BaseController {
}
```

Comment: Try checking this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add **server.context-path** into your controller RequestMapping as it is already handled by spring boot as base path. So if you are using server.context-path as something all your mapping will be prefixed with **server.context-path** value.

You can just use your code like this

```
server.port=8080
server.context-path=/SekcjaN
```

Controller file looks like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth")
public class AuthController extends BaseController {
}
```

Your code will perfectly be called by using `<domain>:<port>/SekcjaN/auth/..`

Comment: So this request should work? `http://localhost:8080/SekcjaN/auth/login`

Comment: I use this in Http configuration. `.anyRequest().authenticated();`  Then shows me unahthorized.

Comment: Your spring-security is blocking the access you have to permit '/login' path

Comment: You can use something like this `http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();`

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't, it's already implied. The mappings are relative to the web application context path (to be precise: relative to the dispatcher servlet that is by default mapped on the root path within the application). `server.context-path` configures the path where the entire application is available within the server.