# Spring Boot - Access values from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created an Indexable annotation with an indexName attribute, this annotation has to be placed on top of a class, i want to add a prefix to the indexName that i define in application.yml file

```
application:
  elasticsearch:
    prefix: dev_

@Indexable(indexName = "${application.elasticsearch.prefix}address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Indexable {

  String indexName() default "";

}
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178928/4235401 ?

Comment: @ConfigurationProperties th get the values that are in the application file inside the class, but i want to get it above the class

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276270/5098338. I am sure that this will help. The solution may differ and depends on jdk version. With the help of this tweak you will be able to change the annotation value in runtime.

Comment: thnx @jahra ^^ , I found a problem with the version of jdk, but I found the solution in this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params)

Answer (score 2):

Use the @Value("${yaml.path.to.value}") annotation on the field you want to set the value. For instance for the yaml.path.to.value :

```
yaml:
  path:
    to:
     value: someValue
```

Be careful with the spaces when using yml.