# How to get property value from application.properties file on spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Below is my code and configuration, but I can't get properties' value, **always null**.

---

application.properties

> app.myProperty=1234

class AppProperties:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class AppProperties {

    private String myProperty;

    public String getMyProperty() {
        return myProperty;
    }

    public void setMyProperty(String myProperty) {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    AppProperties appProperties;

    @PostMapping(RoutePath.TEST)
    public ResultVO test() {

        try {

            log.info("property value:" + appProperties.getMyProperty());

            return ResultVOUtil.success(null);

       } catch (Exception ex) {

            return ResultVOUtil.error(CommonUtil.logExceptionError("发生错误。", null, ex));
        }
    }

}
```

log output:

> property value:null

Comment: Remove `@Component` on `AppProperties` you don't need it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Comment: and also can show the package structure

Comment: @Value("${app.myProperty}")
int  myProperty 
user on @Configuration

Comment: @EnableConfigurationProperties({AppProperties.class})

Answer (score 2):

Use `@Value` annotation to read the values from application.properties

```
@Value("${myProperty}")
private String myProperty;
```

Comment: I think that it should be with {...} characters: @Value("${myProperty}")