# How to pick spring option arguments at run time in java class

Tags: spring-boot

I want to know how to pick spring option arguments like

```
--server.port , --spring.config.name
```

in a java class.

Basically I want to know the value of this argument at run time to load some property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Comment: show the code that you have

Answer (score 0):

You can access them in your application's `main()` method. A [great blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments) about this topic covers it in detail. Following is how you can do it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(String arg:args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adil, Thanks for your response. But in particular, I want to know it through some annotation.

Comment: look at https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-passing-command-line-arguments-example/, you can later do something like "@Value("server.port")

Comment: I looked at these articles earlier but these are not working.

Comment: you need to fetch the property values in java class ryt? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @AkhilSK Yes using some annotations or something like this.  @Value("${spring.config.name}")
 private String springConfigName;

Answer (score 0):

Please try using spring `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`,

```
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getPropertyValue(String key) {
            return env.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

OR

In `application-<env>.propeties` (if using spring.profiles)
else `application.properties`

```
myapp.property=007
```

In your class :

```
@Value("${myapp.property}")
private String myProperty;
```