# How to split value of property in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I want to split a value of property defined application.properties and use it as a value for another property.

Following are my properties in application.properties file

```
test.product.release.version=2003.1
test.product.release.year=${test.product.release.version}.split('.')[0]
```

I want value for property `test.product.release.year` as `2003`

I tried split using `${test.product.release.version}.split('.')[0]` but when I gets the property in my controller I still gets value as `2003.1.split('.')[0]`

How can I get it as `2003` only?

Comment: why don't you load it as array?

Comment: @Deadpool I don't want that because I want to use property `test.product.release.year` as value for another property again.

Comment: try my answer, i tested it and working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the year in controller directly

```
@Value("#{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('[.]')[0]}")
private String year;
```

In the same way for version

```
@Value("#{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('[.]')[1]}")
private String version;
```

In the same way you can specify this expression in properties file also

```
test.product.release.version=2003.1
test.product.release.year="#{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('[.]')[0]}"
test.product.release.version="#{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('[.]')[1]}"
```

And then use `@Value` to read `test.product.release.year`

```
@Value("${test.product.release.year}")
private String value;
```

Comment: `test.product.release.version="#{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('[.]')[1]}"
` is still gives me value as `"#{'V2003.1'.split('[.]')[0]}"` I am fetching it through [AbstractEnvironment](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.21.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html) #getProperty

Comment: why don't you use `@Value` ?

Comment: because you mentioned in answer _In the same way you can specify this expression in properties file also_

Comment: check my updated answer it works for me on both `yml` and `properties` file @Sameer

Comment: and also i tested by using `env.getProperty("test.product.release.year"` it gives me `"#{'2003.1'.split('[.]')[0]}"`, so just use `@Value` instead of `env`

Comment: And also you can ask different question why it is returning expression instead of value while using `Env` sorry i don't have that information @Sameer

Answer (score 1):

For my perspective, you should look through a different point of view :

```
test.product.release.version.year=2003
test.product.release.version.sub=1
test.product.release.version=${test.product.release.version.year}.${test.product.release.version.sub}
```

Comment: I can not use two properties because value for property `test.product.release.version.year` is not controlled by installer which I don't want to touch

Answer (score 1):

Use the following expression. This will work.

```
@Value("#{\"${test.product.release.version}\".split(\"\\.\")}")
private String[] myValues;

// this will give you year part.
@Value("#{\"${test.product.release.version}\".split(\"\\.\")[0]}")
private String year;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to have a single property and derive another out of the first one, it would be better to do it as below:

**application.properties**

```
test.product.release.version=2003.1
```

**Config class**

```
@Value("${test.product.release.version}")
private String version;
@Value("#{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('\\.')[0]}")
private String year;
```

Comment: If the version is not configured `{'${test.product.release.version}'.split('\\.')[0]}` will break.

Comment: @JobinJoseph having `test.product.release.version` defined is a prerequisite as part of the question itself. It is obvious that if it is not defined and used with @Value, the app wouldn't start at all.

Comment: So it is better to use `@ConfigurationProperties` see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178928/2893693

Comment: @JobinJoseph `@ConfigurationProperties` is just another way of using properties, but that is not the point of the question.