# property read from application.properties returning null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am new to springboot and i am trying to read the property value from the application.properties file in the location(src/main/resources). But it always return null. I need help for the same. Attaching the classes and property files.
Please note: I have tried different ways from "https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring "[How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)".
But this is not helping in getting the value from the application.properties file.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            SampleTest ap=new SampleTest();
            System.out.println("+++++++++++++ "+ap.returnvalue());

        }


    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class SampleTest {

        @Value("${testValue}")
        String value1;

        public String returnvalue()
        {
            return value1;
        }
    }
```

**application.properties** file

```
        testValue=Value from application
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>ReadValue</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.read.vale</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>com.read.vale</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: You are creating an instance of `SampleTest` yourself, hence Spring cannot handle it. Use the one from the `ApplicationContext` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   SampleTest ap = ctx.getBean(SampleTest.class);
   System.out.println("+++++++++++++ "+ap.returnvalue());

    }
```