# How to read values from properties file and use it in final class

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my final class "Constants"

```
@Component
public final class Constants {

    @Value("${db2.schema}")
    private static String Schema;

    public static final String STUDENT_TABLE = Schema + ".Student";
}
```

I have db2.schema in my properties file :

```
db2.schema = ${DB2_SCHEMA}
DB2_SCHEMA = D5677ESB
```

Comment: You can create a method, and use it in a static context. What have you tried, what worked and what did not, what was the error?

Comment: Thanks! I tried using @Value as shown above to get the value, but I am getting null as Schema.. What would be the best way.. I am new to springboot..

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot) this may help

Answer (score -1):

@Value can not be used with static fields

Answer (score -1):

You can use like:
...
public class Constants {

```
public static final String NewOrder = "neworder";
public static final String POST = "POST";
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
public static final String APPLICATION_TYPE = "application/json";
public static final String ACCEPT = "Accept";
public static final String CART_URL = PropsUtil.get("order.inquiry.search.insertCartDataURL");
```

}
...
** or check this code:**
...
public String getPropValues() throws IOException {

```
    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "config.properties";

        inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }

        Date time = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // get the property value and print it out
        String user = prop.getProperty("user");
        String company1 = prop.getProperty("company1");
        String company2 = prop.getProperty("company2");
        String company3 = prop.getProperty("company3");

        result = "Company List = " + company1 + ", " + company2 + ", " + company3;
        System.out.println(result + "\nProgram Ran on " + time + " by user=" + user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    return result;
} ...
```