# How an object can be available to all classes in java?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I am creating an application with many java classes. for keeping the configurable information like **username, urls', file paths** etc, I am using **resources/app.properties** file.

For reading values from this file, I am using below code

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("../resources/app.properties");
     
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.load(input);
     
System.out.println("print the url" + prop.getProperty("username"));
```

as we can see from the code, for reading any property from **app.properties** file, we need **prop**
object.

can we write this code in such a way that we just need to write first 3 lines once in the code in the main calss and then we can call **prop.getProperty("username")** from any class in our whole application?

Comment: Declare the Properties variable as a public static class member of your Main class.
Also, there is [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot) , if you just want to access properties from your app.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple.

Define configuration, like

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

@Value("classpath:test.properties")
private Resource resource;

@SneakyThrows // this is from lombok dependency. You can handle exception
@Bean
public Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(this.resource.getInputStream());
    return properties;
}

}
```

Autowire this class wherever you need it.

```
@Autowired private TestConfiguration configuration;
```

Use: `this.configuration.getProperties().getProperty("username")` to get username and same for other fields.

By doing this way, you can achieve a singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about static methods...
or maybe think about the singleton pattern.