# How to access properties @value using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would to read application.properties using `@Value`.

app.properties

```
JDBC_DRIVER =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
DB_URL =jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/vetobooks?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
USER =root
PASS =a
```

main

```
package com.example.java_spring_java_example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;


@SpringBootApplication
    public class main {
            
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(main.class, args);
            context.getBean(JDBCMysql.class);
            
        }

    }
```

JDBCMysql

```
package com.example.java_spring_java_example;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class JDBCMysql {
      @Value("${JDBC_DRIVER}")
        public String JDBC_DRIVE;
       
        @Value("${USER}")
        public String USER;

        @Value("${PASS}")
        public String PASS;

        @Value("${DB_URL}")
        public String DB_URL;
    public void loadValue() {
      System.out.println(DB_URL+"-"+ USER+"-"+ PASS+"...");
    }
       }
```

I get null-null-null as a result. How can I get the real values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Comment: 1. Use the spring managed isntance 2. `@Value` won't work on `static` fields.

Comment: no i read this before :) , what i have to modify on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access spring bean statically as you have done. Please access the bean as below in main method. And make method in JDBCMysql class non-static.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(main.class, args);
JDBCMysql jdbcmysql = context.getBean(JDBCMysql.class);
jdbcmysql.loadValue();
```

Moreover, I see space with every property. Remove space and it should work.

```
JDBC_DRIVER=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/vetobooks?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
USER=root
PASS=a
```

Comment: i added this code inside main class but nothing happened

Comment: have you removed static form loadValue method ?

Comment: yes of course , 020-10-19 15:35:46.140  INFO 2508 --- [           main] c.example.java_spring_java_example.main  : Started main in 0.703 seconds (JVM running for 1.466) nothing after

Comment: you also have to call the method to print the value :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are using the static keyword.. You can do this but you must then have non static setters ..

i.e. Try this instead ..

```
public static String USER;
    
    @Value("${USER}")
    public void setUSER(String user) {
        .....
    }
```