# Spring Boot define global variable and use it in the method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to **define** global **variable** in **application yaml** like this:

**thresholdValue : 5**

and I want to use this in the code like this (i don't know usage but for example):

```
if(application.yaml{"thresholdValue"} >= value){
......
}
```

i searched this question but i found different answers. How can i do this?

Comment: you can add it in a properties file, and use it with: @Value("$thresholdValue}")private int myValue;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Comment: @crizzis similar but i think my question is a little bit different from this.