# How to find "spring.datasource.url=" for application.properties?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am a beginner at developing.

**How to get"spring.datasource.url=" for application.properties?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5YyA.png)

**application.properties**

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sms?useSSL=fals&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimecode=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123123

#Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

#Hibernate auto ddl
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

My Database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xwuZ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `dataSourceProperties`, and use `determineUrl`:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;

...


@Autowired
DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;
```

You can then call:

```java
String dbUrl = dataSourceProperties.determineUrl();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can used Properties:

package java.util.Properties

```
Properties springProperties = new Properties();
springProperties.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
```

learn more => https://www.javatpoint.com/properties-class-in-java