# How to get out of static context in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

Both methods, "createToken" and "getAuthentication" return errors when being used in class "JWTAuthenticationFilter" and "JWTAuthorizationFilter". The errors are `Non-static method 'getAuthentication(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context`

The problem is that I don't have a single static field in all my code, so I don't understand the error. I also can't just declare the methods as static because I need to use the variable "jwt_secret" and [in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246699/implementing-variable-from-application-properties-returns-null) someone explained why I shouldn't make it static:

"Spring will not inject (autowire) into static fields.; that wouldn't make any sense even if it could. Spring beans are instances of classes, but static fields are not associated to any one instance. There are some ugly workarounds but better would be to eliminate the use of static fields."

TokenUtils

```
package com.XX.ZZ.security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.*;

@Component
public class TokenUtils {

    @Autowired
    @Value("${custom.data.jwt.secret}")
    private final String jwt_secret;

    public TokenUtils(String jwtSecret) {
        jwt_secret = jwtSecret;
    }

    public String createToken(String name, String email){
        long expirationTime = 86400 * 1000;
        Date expirationDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expirationTime);

        Map<String, Object> extra = new HashMap<>();
        extra.put("name", name);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(email)
                .setExpiration(expirationDate)
                .addClaims(extra)
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(jwt_secret.getBytes()))
                .compact();
    }

    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(String token){
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey(jwt_secret.getBytes())
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();

            String email = claims.getSubject();

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null, Collections.emptyList());
        } catch (JwtException e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

JWTAuthorizationFilter, error in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePAT = TokenUtils.getAuthentication(token)`

```
package com.XX.ZZ.security;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if(bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            String token = bearerToken.replace("Bearer ", "");
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePAT = TokenUtils.getAuthentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePAT);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter, error in `String token = TokenUtils.createToken`

```
package com.XX.ZZ.security;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        AuthCredentials authCredentials = new AuthCredentials();

        try {
            authCredentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getReader(), AuthCredentials.class);
        } catch (IOException e){ }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePAT = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authCredentials.getEmail(),
                authCredentials.getPassword(),
                Collections.emptyList()
        );

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(usernamePAT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

         UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authResult.getPrincipal();
         String token = TokenUtils.createToken(userDetails.getName(), userDetails.getUsername());

         response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

         response.getWriter().flush();

        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling it as `TokenUtils.getAuthentication(token)` you are literally calling it as as if it is a static. You need an instance in `JWTAuthenticationFilter`:

```
TokenUtils tokenUtilsInstance = new TokenUtils("my secret");

tokenUtilsInstance.getAuthentication(token)
```

You probably need to drop the constructor `TokenUtils(String jwtSecret)`. That will allow the following in `JWTAuthenticationFilter`. Much better Spring practice.

```
@Autowired
TokenUtils tokenUtilsInstance;
```

Comment: Take the @Autowired and final for jwt_secret out.

Comment: That throws the same error, this fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765032/18895342