# How to read values from application.properties inside controller advice file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to access a value from `application.properties` in `RestControllerAdvice` file. The value is not getting read as the advice bean loads first i guess. Is there any way to bring in the value from `application.properties` file into advice file.

`@Value` annotation reads `null` from `application.properties` in advice controller.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30528430/19835740) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38314645/19835740) answer your question ? Also please add example of what you tried.

Comment: There is far too little information here. If the `@Value` isn't resolved and you don't get an error upon startup (that it cannot resolve the value) means your class isn't controlled by Spring.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

For example:

In application.properties file:

```
expired.time=1440
```

In any file, import:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

...

public class AnyClass {

    @Value("${expired.time}")
    private Integer expiredTime;

}
```

Comment: This will not work, the class needs to be annotated with (at)Controller or (at)Component