# Unable to create bean from @Value in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `@Configuration` class where I am grabbing a properties file from my `src/main/resources` directory. The contents of the properties file is like this ...

```
 overall.score=80
 name.score=91
 address.score=30
```

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

  @Value("${overall.score}")
  private String overallScore;

  @Bean
  public String overallScore() {
   return overallScore;
  }

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
   return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

I am not totally sure what this does or if I even need it - `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()`.

Then I have a `@Component` class

```
@Component
public class MatchThresholds {

  @Autowired
  private String overallScore;

}
```

I am getting `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and I am unsure why.

I followed one of the answers here.

[How to access a value defined in the application.properties file in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

I've also tried just adding this to my `@Component` class directly with the `@Value` annotations and the `overallScore` variable is returning as `null`. Like so.

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MatchThresholds {

  @Value("${overall.score}")
  private String overallScore;

  @Bean
  public String overallScore() {
   return overallScore;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the content of `application.properties` file?

Comment: Sure, it looks like this:
overall.score=80
name.score=91
address.score=30

Comment: Added to post. There's nothing else in it but a list of scores like score=91, score=80, etc with a different prefix for each

Comment: Adding the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't make any sense in a Spring Boot application. Not does the exposing of the value as a bean for that matter.  Simply put an `@Value` cannot be `null` your application wouldn't even start if that would be the case, hence the only conclusion is you aren't using Spring to manage the actual instance you are using.

Comment: So how you properly use Spring to pull a resources file and assign the values to a variable?  I followed the sixth answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot

Comment: Just speculating, but It might be related to the spring bean lifecycle where `MatchThresholds`'s @Bean is executed before @Value is executed, so the result of `overallScore()` is null.  Consider using constructor injection, and add breakpoints and see which one is inovked first.