# How to Inject Parameters into @Service Bean Method during Spring Initialization

Tags: spring-boot, parameters

I have a class annotated with @Service. I have a parameterized method that needs to be executed only once while creating the bean. I don't know how to pass the parameter when I autowire or inject via a constructor. I don't want to create a bean of this class. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

```
@Service
public class MyEngine {

    private KieBase kbase = null;
    int num;

    public RuleEngine(String rulesFile) throws HTException {
        loadEngine(rulesFile); // I want this method to be executed only once
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't want to create a bean of this class", of which class do you not want to create a bean? Where does the parameter come from? If the parameter comes from an application property, it sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/30528255/1915448.

Comment: No, it is not coming from a property file. I want to manually pass it in some other class and also during testing