# spring boot @Value injection

Tags: spring-boot

How I can inject @Value to my project in the Spring Boot app?
I'm creating Spring Boot app and @Value doesn't work is 0 like below on the snipped of code.
How I can add them to the class-path or inject to the project. Before I was using @Value annotation and was working right now in spring Boot app doesn't work. Why is that?

SERVICE LAYER: - when I'm debugging guestRecordsInRoomHistory: 0

```
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RoomHistoryService implements Serializable {
    @Value("${guest.records.in.room.history}")
    private int guestRecordsInRoomHistory;
    @Autowired
    private RoomHistoryDao roomHistoryDao;
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1369009886889685771L;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoomHistoryService.class);

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<RoomHistoryDto> getRoomHistoriesByRoomNumber(int roomNumber) {
        List<RoomHistory> roomHistories = roomHistoryDao.getRoomHistoriesByRoomNumber(roomNumber);

        List<RoomHistory> limitedRoomHistories = roomHistories.stream()
                .limit(guestRecordsInRoomHistory)
                .toList();

        return limitedRoomHistories.stream()
                .map(this::convertToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "service")
public class DemoApplication {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Application started. Performing startup operations...");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is solution which is working for the test layer:
But here guestRecordsInRoomHistory:1

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
class RoomHistoryServiceTest {

    @Value("${guest.records.in.room.history}")
    private int guestRecordsInRoomHistory;

    @Mock
    private RoomHistoryDao roomHistoryDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private RoomHistoryService roomHistoryService;

    private static final RoomHistory ROOM_HISTORY_JOHN = new RoomHistory(1, 101, LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusDays(3), "John Doe");
    private static final RoomHistory ROOM_HISTORY_ALICE = new RoomHistory(2, 101, LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusDays(2), "Alice Smith");
    private static final RoomHistory ROOM_HISTORY_BOB = new RoomHistory(3, 101, LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), "Bob Johnson");
    private static final String CSV_CONTENT = """
            1,101,2023-08-01,2023-08-10,John Doe
            2,102,2023-10-02,2023-10-12,Alice Smith
            """;
    private static final int ROOM_NUMBER = 101;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetRoomHistoriesByRoomNumber_ReturnsLimitedRoomHistories() {
        int roomNumber = ROOM_NUMBER;
        List<RoomHistory> mockRoomHistories = Arrays.asList(ROOM_HISTORY_JOHN, ROOM_HISTORY_ALICE, ROOM_HISTORY_BOB);
        when(roomHistoryDao.getRoomHistoriesByRoomNumber(roomNumber)).thenReturn(mockRoomHistories);

        List<RoomHistoryDto> limitedRoomHistories = roomHistoryService.getRoomHistoriesByRoomNumber(roomNumber);

        verify(roomHistoryDao, times(1)).getRoomHistoriesByRoomNumber(roomNumber);

        // Assert that the returned list has the correct size (limited by guestRecordsInRoomHistory)
        assertEquals(guestRecordsInRoomHistory, limitedRoomHistories.size());
    }
```

why isn't working for the Service Layer?

Comment: please add the code instead of images, so it will be easier to read and solve your issue!

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan do You know how to solve this issue? Can You tag them. Like theam

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should make your value property accessible in your **application.properties** (or **application.yml**) file in resources directory.

Here is a simple example: [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528255/how-to-access-a-value-defined-in-the-application-properties-file-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I have to add them to the class path if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

The issue is related to the guestRecordsInRoomHistory value not being injected into the RoomHistoryService during the test execution. In your RoomHistoryService class, the guestRecordsInRoomHistory field is annotated with @Value("${guest.records.in.room.history}"), which means it expects a value to be injected from a properties file or configuration.

During the test, the field guestRecordsInRoomHistory might not get initialized or injected unless you provide a mechanism for injecting it. One way to resolve this is to use mocking frameworks like Mockito to mock the behavior of the @Value annotation for your test scenarios.

Here's an example of how you might inject/mock the guestRecordsInRoomHistory value in your test:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RoomHistoryServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RoomHistoryDao roomHistoryDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private RoomHistoryService roomHistoryService;

    @Value("${guest.records.in.room.history}")
    private int guestRecordsInRoomHistory;

    // ... other declarations and setup

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

        // Mocking the behavior of @Value injection
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(roomHistoryService, "guestRecordsInRoomHistory", 5); // Set an example value here
    }

    // ... your test methods
}
```